# example for 2 data with same sha256 sum

Tags: sha-256

Is there any example for data that has the same **sha256sum value**?

Or is it impossible to find out with current computational power?

Comment: With our current knowledge and computing power, it's practically impossible to find two distinct messages with the same SHA-256 hash. See other linked questions stating and explaining this.

Comment: There are 2 things you can assume there's ***example*** with cryptography. 1. If something hasn't been used in cryptography, you can imagine someone came up with an example of breaking it (e.g. chaos-based crypto). 2. If something is said to be an example of secure cryptography, it's safe to assume no one had broken or can break it (e.g. the SHA-256 algorithm).